# Button Link for PDF Download Not Working

Tags: html

I am trying to link my resume button to a PDF file. However, "Safari can't find the file" keeps on popping up.

```
     <div class="page-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                <div class="m-bot-6">
                    <a href="/documents/resume.pdf" class="btn btn-medium btn-circle btn-theme-color"download>Resume</a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My pdf is in the documents folder.

Comment: Use absolute path, and you're fine.

Comment: Try "./documents/resume.pdf", and make sure your file where this code is executed from is just outside the "documents" folder.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with your file path, the path you gave is pointing to the PDF located in documents folder located in root of your drive, try ./documents/resume.pdf

Answer (score 0):

**"/documents/resume.pdf"** is referring to an absolute path.(leading /)

if your page is say **domain.com/somepath/yourpage.htm**
and the the documents folder is **domain.com/documents** it would work

if the documents folder is in the same folder as the web page change it to;
**"documents/resume.pdf"** and it will refer relative to the path instead then the path structure will not get in the way

if the page and PDF are in the same folder **"resume.pdf"** will work

it's always handy to understand absolute and relative paths

also note; most servers are case sensitive so match the names the same